# Computation of Length of Terminating Sequences of Infinite Ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I often enjoy generating terminating sequences for countable (recursive, of course) ordinals. My process is as follows.

Say we pick a natural number, in my case, almost always: two. Then we pick a countable, recursive ordinal, let’s pick $\omega^\omega$, for sake of simplicity. The we define a (descending, hence finite) sequence of ordinals as follows:

- The first term in our sequence is just the original recursive ordinal itself (here $\omega^\omega$).
- If the $i$th term is a nonzero limit ordinal $\lambda$, the $(i+1)$th term is the $n$th term in $\lambda$'s fundamental sequence.
- If the $i$th term is a successor ordinal $\beta$, the $(i+1)$th term is the largest limit ordinal $<\beta$.
- If the $i$th term is $0$, the sequence stops.

In our example, the sequence for $\omega^\omega$ is ($\omega$, $\omega^2$, $\omega^3$, $\cdots$), so the second term is $\omega^2$. The canonical sequence for $\omega^2$ is $(\omega,\omega2,\omega3,...)$, so the third term is $\omega2$. The canonical sequence for $\omega2$ is $(\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3,...)$, so we get $\omega+2$ next. Now we're at a successor ordinal, so we drop down to $\omega$. The fundamental sequence for $\omega$ is just $(1,2,3,...)$ so our next term is $2$, and we then drop to $0$ and terminate, so the whole sequence is $$(\omega^\omega,\omega^2,\omega2,\omega+2,2,0).$$

If I count the number of steps taken to reach $0$ we get $5$. As we know that every decreasing sequence of ordinals is finite, is there a way to compute this number of steps, without manually working through the process.

Any insight would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: What is that you're doing with the successor ordinals? You go from $\omega+2$ to $\omega$ and from $2$ to $0$. How does that work, exactly?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, successor ordinals are just move  down to the nearest limit ordinal, as they don’t have a canonical sequence.

Comment: If you so choose the result can always be 2: pick $\alpha$ and consider the sequence $\alpha, 0$. :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is about the length of the descending sequence found by one specific algorithm. As demonstrated with the example, the result of that algorithm isn't always a sequence of length 2.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, my **joke** (which admittedly isn't that funny) implied that by choosing a better algorithm the calculation becomes easier.

Comment: Yes, if we pick $n = 0$ and we take the 0th element of each ordinals canonical sequence, it does make a pattern quite clear...

Comment: This is still as clear as  mud

Comment: I've made a rather major edit to clarify the question (and in particular incorporate the OP's comment above, re: successor ordinals). I think it's reasonably clear, though, that this was what the OP intended to say. Of course if anyone disagrees with my interpretation, or feels I've overstepped, feel free to roll back.

Comment: To the OP, there is still one objection to the question: there is no such thing as "the" fundamental sequence for a countable nonzero limit ordinal (indeed we can prove results along the lines of "there is no definable way to assign a fundamental sequence to each countable nonzero limit ordinal"). So this should all be relative, not just to the starting ordinal and the indexing natural number, but also the assignment of fundamental sequences to everything up to our starting ordinal.

Comment: This matters since the behavior will be extremely dependent on this assignment, to the point that I don't think much can be said at all. So while I agree it's a fun game to play, I'm not sure there's a good question here yet.

Comment: If you could come up with a way to explain what I mean (if you understand it), be my guest. And also, your edit is perfect, and worded a lot better than my own explanation.

Comment: You clearly have a lot more experience with all this than a high school student  ;).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I just found a page which essentially describes my system of fundamental sequences on the Googology Wikia. [link](https://googology.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_systems_of_fundamental_sequences)

Comment: The Wainer Hierarchy is the one to be used here.

Comment: @L.McDonald Sure, but even that only goes up an initial segment of the countable ordinals. There's no way to assign a fundamental sequence to *each* countable limit ordinal in a nice way.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If you can be bothered to terminate sequence so from ordinals like $\zeta_0$ or the Small Veblen Ordinal, be my guest, but it would likely take the rest of your life.

Comment: @L.McDonald I don't really understand your comment, but it seems misguided: in general even "large" ordinals can have "quick" descent sequences. For example, given any (necessarily messy) assignment of fundamental sequences to all countable limit ordinals, there is some $n$ such that uncountably many ordinals have descent sequence of length $<n$ (this is just the pigeonhole principle). So it's actually not impossible, or at least there's no a priori reason to believe that.

Comment: @NoahSchweber What I mean is that often larger ordinals have larger terminating sequences. At one point I started with $\zeta_0$ and I never finished.

Comment: Also if you give me an example of a large ordinal with a quick terminating sequence, it would definitely help your argument.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was earlier working through the terminating sequence for $\varepsilon_1$ and I made a mistake, kind of. Several (actually about 40) times I wrote $\omega^{\varepsilon_0}$ which is equal to $\varepsilon_0$. But in doing this, I ended up with a longer terminating sequence. What’s I’m saying is that the length of the sequence for $\varepsilon_0$ Is 7, where’s the sequence for $\omega^{\varepsilon_0}$ is 32. So this process for terminating sequences, if given a ‘function’ $f$, would lead to statements like $\alpha = \beta \not\Rightarrow f(\alpha) = f(\beta)$...

Comment: @NoahSchweber I also don’t think that larger ordinals can’t have shorter terminating sequences. I think that $\alpha > \beta \Rightarrow f(\alpha) \ge f(\beta)$

Comment: Consider a family of fundamental sequences satisfying $(\omega^2)[n]=\omega\cdot n$ and $(\omega\cdot n)[k]=k$ for $k\le n$, otherwise let $(\omega\cdot n)[k]$ be whatever you want. Then your game ends in only 3 steps for $\omega^2$, though it can take longer for smaller ordinals.

Comment: Also, this is approximately the slow growing hierarchy.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I generally like to let $(\omega \cdot n)[k] = \omega\cdot (n-1) + k$

Comment: As I found set theory through googology about 5 years ago, I generally like to use the fundamental sequences used for the fast and slow growing hierarchies.

Comment: The growing hierarchies do not come equipped with fundamental sequences, you have to define them yourself, as Noah Schweber said. And the point is not what fundamental sequence *you* want, it's the matter I've provided a fundamental sequence that gives you an answer to your question.